# Flash Audio Recorder and Player on a website

Tags: php, html, flash

I'm a newbie in website designing and I'm stuck with a problem. I want to accomplish the following and I don't know flash:

1. I want to create a webpage where I can record users voice using his microphone and then save it on the server.
2. Once it's done i would like to access the same recording and then play it on the browser.

I want a step by step approach.

Comment: I want a pony. Hint: this isn't a "do my work for me" site.

Comment: I want a pony doesn't always mean go and fetch it for me. I am asking to tell me how, i will do it myself....

Comment: In that case, step one is putting your question title into Google. https://www.google.com/search?q=Flash+Audio+Recorder+and+Player+on+a+website

Comment: @ceejayoz Nice to see this conversation after a long time. Now I know how to google and this is the advice I give to my peers :)

Comment: It's the single best skill of a good programmer. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips:

1. Look into developing for Flash with some [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html) variant.
2. Then start with an example like [this](https://github.com/samaybhavsar/Flex-Audio-Recorder/blob/master/audio_recorder.mxml).

Some good keywords to use in your Bing search are `flex`, `flash`, `actionscript`, or `spark`.